# Implement foldr function in Scheme from scratch

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I am practicing scheme and I am looking into how I can implement the `foldr` function in scheme, hopefully in a tail recursive manner.

For example:

`(my-foldr + 0 '(1 2 3 4)) => 10`

`(my-foldr list '() '(1 2 3 4)) => '(1 (2 (3 (4 ())))))`

I started my practice by implementing map in scheme, but I can't seem to get foldr. If anyone had any suggestions that would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the `foldr` implementation code you've written so far, pointing the exact part that's giving you trouble. Also post sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: `foldr` should be defined so that `(foldr f z [a, ...])` == `(f a (foldr f z [...]))` and `(foldr f z [])` == `z`. worry about efficiency later, esp. that under Racket (which you seem to be using) there's no advantage to defining it as tail recursive a.o.t. tail recursive modulo "cons" (i.e. modulo `f`).

Answer (score 0):

This is simplified foldr/ foldl for only one list:

```
(define (my-foldr proc init lst)
  (my-foldl proc init (reverse lst)))

(define (my-foldl proc init lst)
  (if (empty? lst) init
      (my-foldl proc
                (proc (car lst) init)
                (cdr lst))))
```

For more lists:

```
(define (my-foldr proc init lst . lsts)
  (apply my-foldl proc init (reverse lst) (map reverse lsts)))

(define (my-foldl proc init lst . lsts)
  (if (empty? lst) init
      (apply my-foldl proc
                (apply proc (append (list (car lst))
                                    (map car lsts)
                                    (list init)))
                (cdr lst)
                (map cdr lsts))))
```

Example:

```
(my-foldl (lambda (a b result)
           (* result (- a b)))
         1
         '(1 2 3)
         '(4 5 6))` => -27
```